# DefinitelyTyped Lodash

Tags: typescript, lodash, definitelytyped

I want to import single function from `lodash` while preserving typings. Such as this:

```
import invokeMap from 'lodash/invokeMap';
```

But it seems that I cannot do so. Compiler says that there is no module `lodash/invokeMap`. It's correct — [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) declares only top-level module for `lodash`, so I can import only the whole package. But I want to import only one function.

Is there a way to import only typings information about lodash without importing lodash itself?

Below is my workaround plan. I want to use standard CommonJS `require` function to import the necessary function without types information and then cast type onto it:

```
declare var require;

var invokeMap: _.invokeMap = require('lodash/invokeMap');
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
               Here I want to cast proper type from DefinitelyTyped,
               but how to reach that `invokeMap` typings alone?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current typings lodash this should work as you tried it before:

```
import invokeMap from 'lodash/invokeMap';
```

just install a current version of the ambient dependencies like so:

```
typings i -SA github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/lodash/lodash.d.ts#672afd8f7b09d839b61eeb4867753876cf79c8b6
```

Answer (score 2):

As of TypeScript 2, you can install typings directly from npm:

`npm install @types/lodash`

Those typings have declarations for each individual module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **object destructuring** to import only the **invokeMap** function from the module.

```js
import {invokeMap} from 'lodash';

invokeMap([[5, 1, 7], [3, 2, 1]], 'sort');
```

Comment: won't it still import all `lodash` package while using only one function from it? I don't want to import whole lodash to prevent increasing the size of my library, because it's intended to be used in browser.

Comment: you can't import just one function from a file, it's just not how javascript works. The module loader will always load the entire file. :)

Comment: by importing from `lodash/invokeMap` in JS I import only one function `invokeMap`, because there is a file `invokeMap.js` in `lodash` directory. It significantly decreases the size of code.

Comment: you'll have to share your project setup, typings provides only 1 .d.ts file for lodash, thus 1 module. :)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Then lodash typings could be improved to allow using partial imports. Such as `core-js` typings do: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/core-js/core-js.d.ts#L1474-L3032

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/8816
If authors agree I will create a PR with such improvement.

Comment: Works like a charm for me :)
By the way, the PR was merged into master.

Comment: @svi3c I'll have a look and update the answer to fit the changes if needed. :)