# In typescript, how to do import merge from "lodash/merge"

Tags: javascript, typescript

With es6, I can import just one function from a library to minimise the whole bundle, like:

`import merge from "lodash/merge"`

However, in typescript, the above sentence will cause a compile error: Cannot find module "lodash/merge". How to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DefinitelyTyped Lodash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373959/definitelytyped-lodash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

The modern way to do that is to use the individual packages. e.g. for `merge` you would install and use `lodash.merge` i.e.

```
import merge from 'lodash.merge'
```

> PS: Ensure `"esModuleInterop": true` is in your `tsconfig.json` as its needed for the ES default import of merge to work.

## Old Answer

> Cannot find module "lodash/merge". How to solve it

The definitions for TypeScript don't support individual loading of lodash members. So you can only `import * as _ from "lodash"`.

Comment: Why on earth is this the accepted answer? :/

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can import a single function using the `'lodash.merge'` library

```js
import merge from 'lodash.merge'

const result: any = merge(obj1, obj2)
```

**BUT**

You need to add this property to the tsconfig.json `"esModuleInterop": true`
without this it will not work

[cit]
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3192#issuecomment-411963038

Comment: THIS has to be the solution to your question!

Comment: @TakácsBotond -  Not if you use lodash for other purposes. This will result in both libraries loaded.

Comment: Looks like `lodash.merge` hasn't been updated for a while and is out-of-sync with the main `lodash` package on NPM